# How does Matlab `surf` perform interpolation?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

When I use Matlab's `surf` function, I notice that I can't re-perform its interpolation, which produces unreliable results. Do you know what does `surf` do under the hood?

The following code compares `spline` and `surf` interpolation:

```
z= linspace(-1,1,4001);
x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,150);
sharp_gausian = @(y,sigma) exp((-y.^2).*sigma);

% initializing low-resolution surf
for j=1:length(z)
    psi_grid(j,:) = sharp_gausian(x + sin(5*z(j)),10);
end
subplot(2,2,1)
s =surf(x,z, psi_grid);
set(s,'linestyle','none')
xlabel('$x$' , 'FontSize', 14, 'Interpreter', 'latex');
ylabel('$z$', 'FontSize', 14, 'interpreter', 'latex','rot',0);
title('$Nx = 150$')

% using higher resolution grid and interpolating the function using spline.
x_fine = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,1500);
for j=1:length(z)
    psi_grid2(j,:) = spline(x, psi_grid(j,:), x_fine);
end
subplot(2,2,2)
s2 =surf(x_fine,z, psi_grid2);
set(s2,'linestyle','none')
xlabel('$x$' , 'FontSize', 14, 'Interpreter', 'latex');
ylabel('$z$', 'FontSize', 14, 'interpreter', 'latex','rot',0);
title('$Nx = 1500$')
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are interested in how the `surf` function controls the coloring of the surfaces. Most of the information is readily available at the Matlab help pages for [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) and [`shading`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shading.html).

By default, `surf` uses `faceted` shading, so *"each mesh line segment and face has a constant color determined by the color value at the endpoint of the segment or the corner of the face that has the **smallest index** or **indices**"*. So, in your code — no explicit interpolation has been performed.

By introducing a fine grid and using `spline`, you performed interpolation by yourself, and now `surf` function for $N_x=1500$ just uses the result you fed it.

In the picture below, I demonstrated the work of `surf` function with different `shading` options. It is clear, that `surf` with `shading interp` for $N_x=150$ (bottom-left) pretty much resembles the figure obtained with a fine ($10\times$) grid $N_x=1500$ (bottom-right). `shading flat` and `shading faceted` look the same because you manually disabled lines for the surface plots.

[image]

Matlab code:

```
sharp_gausian = @(y,sigma) exp((-y.^2).*sigma);

Nz=4001;
Nx=150;
Nx_refine=Nx*10;
z=linspace(-1,1,Nz);
x=linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,Nx);
x_fine=linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,Nx_refine);

% initializing low-resolution surf
psi_grid=zeros(Nz,Nx);
for j=1:length(z)
    psi_grid(j,:)=sharp_gausian(x+sin(5*z(j)),10);
end

% using higher resolution grid and interpolating the function using spline.
psi_grid2=zeros(Nz,Nx_refine);
for j=1:length(z)
    psi_grid2(j,:)=spline(x,psi_grid(j,:),x_fine);
end

%% ONLY VISUALIZATION AFTER THIS POINT
set(groot,'DefaultTextInterpreter','latex');
set(groot,'defaultLegendInterpreter','latex');
set(groot,'defaultAxesTickLabelInterpreter','latex'); 
ff=20;

figure(1)
set(gcf,'Units','inches');
set(gcf,'Position',[2 2 13 12]);
% original x, flat shading
subplot(2,2,1)
s1=surf(x,z, psi_grid);
shading flat;
set(s1,'linestyle','none')
xlabel('$x$','FontSize', ff, 'Interpreter', 'latex');
ylabel('$z$','FontSize', ff, 'interpreter', 'latex','rot',0);
title('$N_x = 150$, shading flat');
set(gca,'FontSize',ff-2);
% original x, faceted (default) shading
subplot(2,2,2)
s2=surf(x,z, psi_grid);
shading faceted;
set(s2,'linestyle','none')
xlabel('$x$' , 'FontSize', ff, 'Interpreter', 'latex');
ylabel('$z$', 'FontSize', ff, 'interpreter', 'latex','rot',0);
title('$N_x = 150$, shading faceted');
set(gca,'FontSize',ff-2);
% original x, inerpolated shading
subplot(2,2,3)
s3=surf(x,z, psi_grid);
shading interp;
set(s3,'linestyle','none')
xlabel('$x$' , 'FontSize', ff, 'Interpreter','latex');
ylabel('$z$', 'FontSize', ff, 'interpreter','latex','rot',0);
title('$N_x = 150$, shading interp');
set(gca,'FontSize',ff-2);
% 10* refinement in x, faceted (default) shading
subplot(2,2,4)
s4=surf(x_fine,z, psi_grid2);
shading faceted;
set(s4,'linestyle','none')
xlabel('$x$','FontSize',ff,'Interpreter','latex');
ylabel('$z$','FontSize',ff,'interpreter','latex','rot',0);
title('$N_x = 1500$, shading default (faceted)');
set(gca,'FontSize',ff-2);
```